# See who reset iOS Distribution Provisioning Profile

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning

I have several people sharing the distribution profile for an iOS developer account.

Is there a way to see the log of when or who reset the iOS distribution profile certificates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None that I have found.  Your best bet to prevent this going forward is to have each developer create their own apple ID and add them as team members on the main account.  Otherwise, you will continually have problems when developers inevitably click that "Fix Issue" button in Xcode.

Bottom line, if you manage the profiles manually, teach your developer not to use the Fix Issue button.